# Parsing file with custom tags

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, tags

I am having file with structure something like this

```
<review>
<unique_id>
6301968972:just_as_true_today!:gary_d._thomas_"brass_crass"
</unique_id>
<unique_id>
5139
</unique_id>
<asin>
6301968972
</asin>
<product_name>
Hucksters: Video: Clark Gable,Deborah Kerr,Sydney Greenstreet,Adolphe Menjou,Ava Gardner,Keenan Wynn,Edward Arnold,Aubrey Mather,Richard Gaines,Frank Albertson,Douglas Fowley,Clinton Sundberg,Gloria Holden,Connie Gilchrist,Kathryn Card,Lillian Bronson,Vera Marshe,Ralph Bunker,Virginia Dale,Jimmy Conlin,Jack Conway
</product_name>
<product_type>
video
</product_type>
<product_type>
video
</product_type>
<helpful>
1 of 1
</helpful>
<rating>
5.0
</rating>
<title>
Just as true today!
</title>
<date>
August 4, 2000
</date>
<reviewer>
Gary D. Thomas "Brass Crass"
</reviewer>
<reviewer_location>
Studio City, CaliforniA
</reviewer_location>
<review_text>
Picture this: Clark Gable and the whole passle of MGM stars and starlets!  Spins a great story, and all this in 1947, could be today, except they  dressed better. You will not forget the characterizations, especially  Sydney Greenstreet, eat your heart out Eddie Murphy, just a marvy little  film for all ages (God I love cliches!
</review_text>
</review>
```

and I want it to parse and convert this to datadframe. What are some easy ways to do this?

I have tried XML and HTML parsers but no lucks.
The file contains repetitions of the snippet above,
If there exists any library out there, please mention it.

Thanks

Comment: The [Python xml parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) works fine for me. However, there are duplicate tags, like `unique_id` or `product_type` - how do you plan on handling these?

Comment: Parser gives me erro: ```junk after document element: line x, column y```. I just have to use both ```"unique_id"```s and ```product type``` as I can't skip them

Comment: From the example you posted, I cannot reproduce this. Next issue would be: if you have duplicate entries, making a `pandas` `DataFrame` from this will be difficult.

Comment: maybe your issue is that you have multiple <review></review> clauses in your root - that won't work in xml; you will need to "encapsulate" those under a common tag, e.g. begin your xml file with <content> and end it with </content> ("content" is arbitrary here).

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Please let me know if you have any problems in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following code, you need to install simplified_scrapy

pip install simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<review><unique_id>6301968972:just_as_true_today!:gary_d._thomas_"brass_crass"</unique_id><unique_id>5139
</unique_id><asin>6301968972</asin><product_name>Hucksters: Video: Clark Gable,Deborah Kerr,Sydney Greenstreet,Adolphe Menjou,Ava Gardner,Keenan Wynn,Edward Arnold,Aubrey Mather,Richard Gaines,Frank Albertson,Douglas Fowley,Clinton Sundberg,Gloria Holden,Connie Gilchrist,Kathryn Card,Lillian Bronson,Vera Marshe,Ralph Bunker,Virginia Dale,Jimmy Conlin,Jack Conway
</product_name><product_type>video</product_type><product_type>video</product_type><helpful>1 of 1</helpful><rating>5.0</rating><title>Just as true today!</title><date>August 4, 2000</date><reviewer>Gary D. Thomas "Brass Crass"</reviewer><reviewer_location>Studio City, CaliforniA
</reviewer_location><review_text>Picture this: Clark Gable and the whole passle of MGM stars and starlets!  Spins a great story, and all this in 1947, could be today, except they  dressed better. You will not forget the characterizations, especially  Sydney Greenstreet, eat your heart out Eddie Murphy, just a marvy little  film for all ages (God I love cliches!
</review_text></review>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
doc = doc.getElementByTag('review')
items = doc.getChildren() # get all
for item in items:
  print (item.tag,item.text)

print (doc.unique_id.html) # get one
items = doc.unique_ids # get all nodes of a label
for item in items:
  print (item.tag,item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to solve it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4

my_text = "<review><unique_id>6301968972:just_as_true_today!:gary_d._thomas_"brass_crass"</unique_id><unique_id>5139</unique_id><asin>6301968972</asin><product_name>Hucksters: Video: Clark Gable,Deborah Kerr,Sydney Greenstreet,Adolphe Menjou,Ava Gardner,Keenan Wynn,Edward Arnold,Aubrey Mather,Richard Gaines,Frank Albertson,Douglas Fowley,Clinton Sundberg,Gloria Holden,Connie Gilchrist,Kathryn Card,Lillian Bronson,Vera Marshe,Ralph Bunker,Virginia Dale,Jimmy Conlin,Jack Conway</product_name><product_type>video</product_type><product_type>video</product_type><helpful>1 of 1</helpful><rating>5.0</rating><title>Just as true today!</title><date>August 4, 2000</date><reviewer>Gary D. Thomas "Brass Crass"</reviewer><reviewer_location>Studio City, CaliforniA</reviewer_location><review_text>Picture this: Clark Gable and the whole passle of MGM stars and starlets!  Spins a great story, and all this in 1947, could be today, except they  dressed better. You will not forget the characterizations, especially  Sydney Greenstreet, eat your heart out Eddie Murphy, just a marvy little  film for all ages (God I love cliches!</review_text></review>"


soup = BS4(my_text)

print(soup.prettify())

l_unique = soup.findAll("unique_id")

for l in l_unique:
    print(l.text)
```

It will print

```
6301968972:just_as_true_today!:gary_d._thomas_"brass_crass"
5139
```

You can find the BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)